# More general form of Fourier inversion formula

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-analysis

My question begins as follows: Suppose $G$ is a compact (Lie) group and $A$ is a $G$-module, and denote the action of $G$ on $A$ by $\alpha$. Fix $a\in A$ and view
$$
f:g\mapsto \alpha_g(a)
$$
as an $A$-valued function on $G$.

What is the Fourier transform and the inversion formula of this assignment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  "Please note that the vector bundle $E$ need not carry a $G$ action."  I do not understand your post.  A section of a vector bundle $E$ over $G$ associates to every point $x$ of $G$ an element $s(x)$ of the fiber $E_x$.  Please explain how $s(g^{-1}x)$ is an element in the fiber $E_x$.

Comment: $s(g^{-1}x)$ is indeed not an element of $E_x$, but it belongs to $E_{g^{-1}}$. A section is a function (smooth or continuous) $s:G\rightarrow E$ such that $p\circ s(x)=x$ ($p:E\rightarrow G$ is the projection.)

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  For your notation $g\cdot s$, please explain what element of $E_x$ is the image of the element $x$.

Comment: First of all, sorry there is a typo... $g\cdot s(x)\in E_{g^{-1}x}$. But, this does not change anything because I realized the "concrete setting" part of my question is a complete nonsense for $g\cdot s$ is not a section unless the action or the group is trivial. Thank you for making me become aware.

Comment: What is your question?  I mean, are you looking for a *definition* of the Fourier transform, or *theorems* on it, or …?  Notice that you get a family of scalar-valued functions $g \mapsto \langle a^*, \alpha_g(a)\rangle$ for $a^* \in A^*$, and I would expect the most reasonable definition of the Fourier transform to be the corresponding family of scalar-valued Fourier transforms.